# How to populate a foreign key field within an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework-6

I have two tables in my database. Employee and Picture.

Employee holds general employee credentials and a foreign key called PictureId that references the Picture Table.

[image: Employee table]

The Picture table holds all employee images (and a few other miscellaneous ones) to be used in my application

[image: Picture table]

So in my WPF application I have a UserControl with it's own ViewModel. The ViewModel gets the Employee information from the database (I'm using an Entity-Framework 6 Database First approach).

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private databaseEntities context;
    public List<employee> EmployeeList { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        context = new databaseEntities();
        var queryEmployees = context.employees;
        EmployeeList = new List<employee>(queryEmployees);
    }
}
```

The View (Usercontrol), arranges this information as cards.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}">
    <Grid...>
        <Image Source="/assets/images/CardBackground.PNG" Stretch="Fill" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <!-- How would I fetch the corresponding image data meant to go below? -->
            <Image Source="{Binding Path= ??, Converter={StaticResource PictureConverter}}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ItemsControl>
```

Which is where my problem comes in. I can retrieve information from the Employee table with the above code. But when it comes to getting their display pictures, I've hit a brick wall.

I initially assumed that The Employees Model would first have to load it's dependancy in the same way that a class loads a base class but apparently it doesn't quite work that way.

Creating and populating a separate List doesn't seem to have any effect either.

How would I go about loading a foreign table field within the same ItemsControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Entity FrameWork then there must be navigation property in the Employee class.

Lets say that property is Picture then you can do something like this.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}">
    <Grid...>
        <Image Source="/assets/images/CardBackground.PNG" Stretch="Fill" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <!-- How would I fetch the corresponding image data meant to go below? -->
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Employee.Picture.PicturePath, Converter={StaticResource PictureConverter}}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ItemsControl>
```

I am assuming the name of the Navigation property and the property of the Picture entity. Please provide the definition of Employee class and Picture class so I can edit my answer if required otherwise you will get an idea from the above code what to do

Comment: Turns out that worked. Sort of... I can confirm that the ItemsControl is binding to the required field. The problem is that requested field is always empty because the referenced table (by the foreign key) was never populated. Any idea how to go about that?

Comment: 'The problem is that requested field is always empty because the referenced table (by the foreign key) was never populated'. Can u please explain this a bit ? I didn't get u.

Comment: In my description, the List `EmployeeList<employee>` was populated in the constructor. So my view could convey information in the Employee Table.
However, the List `PuctureList<picture>` was not populated. Therefore the view cannot bring up the picture for the corresponding employee. I'm not sure if I made much sense there

Comment: This description does not depend on any other list in this Window C# code. It depends on the navigation property of the Employee. Please verify by going in Employee.cs class that the navigation property used here is named actually 'Picture' there. Also verify in Picture.cs class the string containing is named 'PicturePath'. If both are different as used in this xaml code than use those same here. Because that must have been the issue

Comment: Turn's out you're right. Your solution worked. I had neglected case sensitivity when it came to the navigation Property. Other than that, your image source binding worked. Much gratitude.

Comment: Yes that thing is case sensitive. Glad I could help :)